# Custom Title for SSRS Map using expression and data field

Tags: reporting-services

I want the Map Title to be an expression which selects a value from the dataset based upon the value from a different column of the same row in the dataset.

Specifically, when the 'Area' column contains 'Unknown' I want to add the row's 'Count' column value to my Title. (This is because there isn't a map area called 'Unknown' to hold that value).

I have used this expression:

```
="Count for Unknown area: " & IIF(Fields!Area.Value.Equals("Unknown"), Fields!Count.Value.ToString(), string.Empty)
```

but it doesn't work - all it shows is "Count for Unknown area: ".

If I change "Unknown" for any other area name, or Equals() for =, it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the expression to a lookup works ;-)

```
="Count for unknown area: " & Lookup("Unknown", Fields!Area.Value, Fields!Count.Value.ToString(), "CountByArea")
```